# caret's helper functions for feature selection: caretSBF and caretFuncts

Tags: r, r-caret

caret provides functions for nested feature selection, via **caretSBF** and **caretFuncs**.

**caretSBF**: for Selection By Filter

```
lmSBF
rfSBF
treebagSBF
ldaSBF
nbSBF
```

**caretFuncs**: for Recursive Feature Selection -- (I assume it's just for historical reasons that the caretFuncs are not called caretRFE?)

```
lmFuncs
rfFuncs
treebagFuncs
ldaFuncs
nbFuncs
gamFuncs
lrFuncs
```

Why is this list of helper functions so much more limited than [caret's full model list](http://topepo.github.io/caret/modelList.html)?  For example, there are no tailored feature selection methods for glmnet's elastic net method, kernlab's svm method, etc.

Is it because:

- these other models work fine with the generic case functions (i.e. caretSBF and caretFuncs)? - though I've run into trouble trying to get glmnet working with caretSBF...
- these other models are not thought to require 'extra help' in feature selection? - I guess a method like elasticnet is thought to do feature selection well, but other methods like SVM certainly do not...
- the package maintainer just hasn't gotten around to writing the specialized functions for other methods? - In which case, could/should the community contribute these helper functions?

Thanks for reading and thanks to the caret package maintainer(s) for the excellent work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a combination of #2 and #3. It does't make sense for models that implicitly do feature selection (e.g. `rpart`, `glmnet` etc). Also, I haven't had time to expand the list (but code submissions are always welcome).

Max